# How would I pass a php variable in API URL

Tags: php

I have an API URL which gives JSON data. I have to pass a variable via the URL. Help me to pass the variable through the URL.

```
<?php
$no=0078915030900;
//$no_url=urlencode("0078915030900");
$jsonurl = 'https://www.outpan.com/api/get-product.php?
barcode=$no&apikey=318c91a99b132a29dda536d63e7fb8b4';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: and you need help to?

Comment: i want to pass $no variable in url

Comment: I think you lack some basic understanding about scalar data types. Something that starts with double-zero cannot be a number. And there's nothing magic in URLs, they're only strings.

Comment: @AbdurRehmanFarooqi you cannot put variables inside single quotes, they are being treated as string only. Use double quotes. Check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way: fopen() or file_get_contents() the URL: fopen("http://google.com/", "r")
        The smart way: Use the cURL library
        The other smart way: http_get() from PHP's http module
        The hard way: Craft a HTTP request and send it with fsockopen() or stream_socket_client()
        The C way: Send a HTTP request using sockets
        The stupid way: call an external tool such as wget or curl through system()

```
None of these is guaranteed to be available on your server though.
```

Comment: Sir, give me solution. I didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

answer as per `OP` commit reply, use string concatenation operator (`.`) to append variable in string url

```
<?php
$no=0078915030900;
//$no_url=urlencode("0078915030900");
$jsonurl = 'https://www.outpan.com/api/get-product.php?
barcode='.$no.'&apikey=318c91a99b132a29dda536d63e7fb8b4';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
echo $json;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

append varaible $no to url:

```
$no=0078915030900;

//$no_url=urlencode("0078915030900");

$jsonurl = 'https://www.outpan.com/api/get-product.php?apikey=318c91a99b132a29dda536d63e7fb8b4' . "&barcode=" . $no;

$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);

echo $json;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't parse variables inside single quote string literals. Either you must use double quotes around your url string, or use a concatenation operator to concatenate variables to your string. These are very basic things.

Like this:

```
$jsonurl = "https://www.outpan.com/api/get-product.php?
barcode=$no&apikey=318c91a99b132a29dda536d63e7fb8b4";
```

OR

```
$jsonurl = 'https://www.outpan.com/api/get-product.php?
barcode='.$no.'&apikey=318c91a99b132a29dda536d63e7fb8b4';
```